# How to query from a dataframe using caching?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df`. This dataframe consists of columns `id`, `time` and `quantity`. I have to make repeated queries to this `df` based on `time`, and the query should return the `id-quantity` pairs corresponding to the query time.

`df` is pre-ordered by `id`, and within each `id` group, it's sorted based on `time` (though the order itself probably won't help much with dataframe querying).

The queries are in somewhat of an alternating order, and there's repeated queries, e.g., we can query in this order: `time = 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30, 20, 30, 20, 30, 20, ....` It's in increasing alternating order, and note that ALL times in `df` will eventually be queried.

Currently, my implementation doesn't involve any caching, and it just simply does:

```
def query(df, time):
  return df[df.time == time][["id", "quantity"]]
```

But I think this may be inefficient. I'm not very well versed with Python and pandas, but my understanding is `df[df.time == time]` can be an expensive operation, especially when `df` is large, which in my case it is, around 100k rows.

How can I do this more efficiently?

One idea I have is, we can use a `dict`, where the keys are `df.time().unique()`, and the values are the rows corresponding to that time, but I am not sure if this is the most efficient approach here.

Comment: `groups = {t: d for t,d in df.groupby('time')}`, then just `groups[t]` everytime you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the index on the timestamp column if the timestamp is unique. This is akin to indexing on relational databases.

Then filtering on timestamp is very efficient and quick and you can do more advanced operations. e.g.

(1) Load the [dataset](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Pandas-Cookbook-Second-Edition/blob/master/data/crime.h5) which has timestamp level data and set an index on it

```py
df=pd.read_hdf(crime.h5)
df=df.set_index('REPORTED_DATE').sort_index()
```

(2) perform filtering

```py
df.loc['2017-09-12'] #get all records by dates
df.loc['21st October 2014 05'] # search by specifying timestamps in different formats
df.loc['2015-3-4':'2016-1-1'] # filters between two dates
```